# Angular returns undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

I have API for getting information about one specific restaurant in the database, but I have to get it with a POST request. I successfully get `restaurantID` from auth.service and another API when the restaurant is logged in, But when I tried to log restaurant in console, I get `undefined`. Uniformly I don't have permission to show API here. The code:

restaurant.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Restaurant } from '../models/Restaurant';
import { LoggedRestaurant } from '../models/LoggedRestaurant';

import { AuthService } from './auth.service'

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RestaurantService {

  private restaurantUrl = 'https://dm.dnevnimeni.com/dmnew/podacirestorana.php';

  public restaurant: Restaurant;
  public loggedRestaurant: LoggedRestaurant
  public restaurantID = this.authService.currRestaurant[0].id

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private authService: AuthService) { }

  getRestaurant(ID): Observable<LoggedRestaurant> {

    console.log('ID je' + this.restaurantID);

    return this.http.post<LoggedRestaurant>(this.restaurantUrl, ID);
  }

}
```

informacije.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { RestaurantService } from '../services/restaurant.service';
import { Restaurant } from '../models/Restaurant';
import { LoggedRestaurant } from '../models/LoggedRestaurant';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-informacije',
  templateUrl: './informacije.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./informacije.component.scss']
})
export class InformacijeComponent implements OnInit {
  restaurant: Restaurant;
  loggedRestaurant: LoggedRestaurant;
  restaurantID = this.authService.currRestaurant[0].id;;

  constructor(private restaurantService: RestaurantService, private authService: AuthService ) { }

  getRestaurant() {
     this.restaurantService.getRestaurant().subscribe(data  => {
      this.loggedRestaurant = data;
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getRestaurant();

    this.restaurant = this.authService.currRestaurant[0];
    console.log(this.restaurant)
    console.log(this.loggedRestaurant)

    this.restaurantID = this.restaurant.id;
    console.log(this.restaurantID)
    this.restaurantService.restaurantID =this.restaurantID;

  }
}
```

Comment: It's probably you call REST service with invalid input. Make sure that rest service works the way you expect it with something like CURL or POSTMAN.

Comment: Where is the line undefined come from ?

Comment: You don't call `getRestaurant` anywhere, so the service call wont be requested.

Comment: `loggedRestaurant` is assigned in the `subscribe` callback. It might not be available when `ngOnInit` is called

Comment: What is `currRestaurant[0]`?

Comment: @wentjun it's the first object in the array because, in API, a restaurant I get is one object in an array

Comment: I see.. Anyways, you should follow @TonyNgo's answer. I believe his code solves what you are trying to achieve, which is to return the observable value by subscribing to it

Answer (score 1):

Update 
Your code should be like this

Since you just need to get data you dont have to use post

so you can change from this

```js
return this.http.post<LoggedRestaurant>(this.restaurantUrl, this.restaurantID);
```

to this

```js
return this.http.get<LoggedRestaurant>(`${this.restaurantUrl}/${this.restaurantID}`);
```

and add in ngOnInit

```js
ngOnInit() {
this.restaurantService.getRestaurant().subscribe(data  => {
   this.loggedRestaurant = data;
   // do something else
});
```

Because your getRestaurant() method is not called in ngOnInit life cycle hook so the data is not avaibled

Comment: Thank you for an answer, but when I tried it, console says ```ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined```

Comment: Please update the screen shot I cant help you if I dont know where is the error come from

Comment: @seven check my answer again

Comment: oh, sorry. Done

Comment: no, I tried it, also tried just to call ```getRestaurant()``` on the start of ```nfOnInit()``` but still getting ```undefined``` and console throws an error, I posted error in the screenshot before in a comment

Comment: Did you try change to get like i suggest ?

Comment: yes, still don't work. The thing is, backend developer said API is formatted in the way where I have to get data via POST request, and in POST to send parameters: API and ID. I tried with postman, when i make POST request with correct ID, it passes and returns correct restaurant

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code. First, you never actually call the `getRestaurant()` function, thus the service call will never be requested.

Second, you're dealing with asynchronous code and can't expect the service call to be complete before the `console.log(this.loggedRestaurant)` is run.

My suggestion is that you change your function to return an `Observable<LoggedRestaurant>` and subscribe to that.

```
getRestaurant(): Observable<LoggedRestaurant> {
     this.restaurantService.getRestaurant().subscribe(data  => {
      this.loggedRestaurant = data;
    });
}
```

Then you can use it as

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getRestaurant().subscribe(loggedRestaurant => {
        console.log(loggedRestaurant);
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

informacije.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';
import { RestaurantService } from '../services/restaurant.service';
import { Restaurant } from '../models/Restaurant';
import { LoggedRestaurant } from '../models/LoggedRestaurant';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-informacije',
  templateUrl: './informacije.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./informacije.component.scss']
})
export class InformacijeComponent implements OnInit {
  restaurant: Restaurant;
  loggedRestaurant: LoggedRestaurant;
  restaurantID;

  constructor(private restaurantService: RestaurantService, private authService: AuthService ) { }

  getRestaurant() {
     this.restaurantService.getRestaurant().subscribe(data  => {
      this.loggedRestaurant = data;
    });

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getRestaurant(); // add this line
    this.restaurant = this.authService.currRestaurant[0];
    console.log(this.restaurant)
    console.log(this.loggedRestaurant)

    this.restaurantID = this.restaurant.id;
    console.log(this.restaurantID)
    this.restaurantService.restaurantID =this.restaurantID;

  }
}
```

Comment: When I try it, the console still returns ```undefined``` plus console says [link](https://prnt.sc/ns7vyc)

Comment: Do you get data in getRestaurant() method.

Comment: nope, from ```getRestaurant()``` in component, I getting ```undefined```, and from ```getRestaurant()``` from service, I got ```Observable ```